# MailKit - SmtpClient Connect method freezes

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mailkit

I'm developing a Xamarin android app where at some point (after a successful transaction) the app must send an information email to the customer. The whole process of creating the MimeMessage instance as well as the actual sending of it is done through a task. The message (which most of the time contains linked images) is created flawlessly but as soon as I call a method to actually send it the execution freezes at that call and the whole task remains active but frozen at that point.

Here's my `SendMail` method which, beside of the `MimeMessage` parameter, receives a MailAccount class with information about the smtp machine, port and sender account. As soon as a call is made to the `Connect` method of the MailKit's `SmtpClient` instance I'm having the "frozen" behavior I described. I tried the whole thing many times - not even once the code continued beyond that line.

```
private static int SendMail(MailAccount account, MimeMessage message)
{
    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            client.Connect(account.Server, account.Port, false);
        }
        catch (SmtpCommandException)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        catch (SmtpProtocolException)
        {
            return -2;
        }

        client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

        if (client.Capabilities.HasFlag(SmtpCapabilities.Authentication))
        {
            try
            {
                client.Authenticate(account.User, Decrypt(account.Pass));
            }
            catch (AuthenticationException)
            {
                return -3;
            }
            catch (SmtpCommandException)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            catch (SmtpProtocolException)
            {
                return -2;
            }
        }

        int status = 1; //assume success

        try
        {
            client.Send(message);
        }
        catch (SmtpCommandException ex)
        {
            switch (ex.ErrorCode)
            {
                case SmtpErrorCode.MessageNotAccepted:
                    status = -6;
                    break;

                case SmtpErrorCode.SenderNotAccepted:
                    status = -5;
                    break;

                case SmtpErrorCode.RecipientNotAccepted:
                    status = -4;
                    break;

                default:
                    status = -7;
                    break;
            }
        }

        client.Disconnect(true);
        return status;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? At which line the code stops? Is it `client.Send(message);` ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you checked this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8505/smtpclient-hanging ? In this discussion the client hangs on `Send`. However, I would suggest you check if this is the problem in your case, the port number.

Comment: First of all, you could refer to this link to create a basic demo, https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-send-mail-directly-from-android-application-in-xamarin-android/, then make sure your port, account, password is correct. Add a breakpoint to debug it, locate line that caused this issue.

Comment: The code hangs at _Client.Connect_ - that's where I place the breakpoint. This code has never proceeded any further. As for the _account_ parameter, I'm using port 25 for all the "experiments". There are actually 7 e-mail accounts that I use for this project (all using port 25) and yes, they work just fine: The android app is using Mailkiet because with the standard .net SmtpClient there's an issue - the linked resources of the message are not been sent.

Comment: Today I tried to use _ServerCertificateValidationCallback_ as a lot of articles suggest and there is a breakpoint hit at that line, but once the connect method is called the execution jumps back to the emulator and nothing happens.

Comment: Does it hang when you run a simple test case in a Console app? Can you connect to port 25 using telnet? What version of MailKit are you using?

Comment: In general, a hang in the Connect method means that you are trying to connect to a host or port that is firewalled or otherwise not allowing connections. Port 25 is not always supported for SMTP, sometimes you need to connect to port 587 or 465.

Comment: @jstedfast - It's an xamarin android application, part of a much bigger project with 4 apps in total. The equivalent application as a desktop application runs at .NET 4, where I use the old .NET smtpclient - I can send messages with all 7 accounts (and all 7 use port 25). The MailKit version I use is the last one (2.1.5.1). As for the SMTP server is part of a domain I'm alredy using: I know that the service is working.

Answer (score 2):

In general, a hang while calling `client.Connect` suggests that the host or port that you are trying to connect with is not available. Check that the host and port are correct.

If they *are* correct, make sure that you are using the latest version of MailKit as some older versions used `Socket.BeginConnect (string, int ...)` which, on IPv6-enabled OS's, would sometimes try to use IPv4 over IPv6 and hang in some situations (such as when a virus scanner like Avast was used).

Newer versions of MailKit (>= 2.1.4 and pre-2.0 versions) do a DNS lookup of the remote host and manually specify the correct address family to use when instantiating the Socket (IPv4 vs IPv6) so as to avoid this problem.

It's also possible that the hang is caused by SSL/TLS certificate revocation checks with an unresponsive Certificate Authority. You can disable certificate revocation checks using the following code snippet:

```
client.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;
```

Just make sure to set that property *before* making the call to `Connect`.

It may be worth testing access to your SMTP server by creating a new Console application in Visual Studio and pasting in the following code and checking that it works:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using MailKit;
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;

namespace ConsoleApp {
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            using (var client = new SmtpClient (new ProtocolLogger ("smtp.log"))) {
                using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource (60000)) {
                    try {
                        client.Connect ("your-host.com", 25, false, cts.Token);
                        client.Disconnect (true);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Console.WriteLine ("Error connecting: {0}", ex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine (ex.StackTrace);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It would also be interesting to know if your Android app has problems connecting to `smtp.gmail.com` on port `465` (`useSsl = true`).

Comment: Well, as I mentioned at my comments above, I use a an SMTP server which I know for certain that accepts messages, where I created 7 accounts for testing my project all using the "unprotected" port 25 (hence the _false_ parameter at the _Connect_ call). What I DIDN'T know was that "magic" property - I willll try it ASAP and let you know - thank you for your recommentations and support.

Comment: Nope, still hanging at the _connect_ method. To be honest a thought had crossed my mind about the relyability of this SMTP server - I'll use something different in the next days: An SMTP server running under windows server 2012 R2 (this is my main data server but I don't thing it's gonna hurt if I install an SMTP service). I'm not quiting MailKit yet - I'll try it and let you know of the results.

Comment: Unless the SMTP server supports the STARTTLS extension, the `CheckCertificateRevocation` property won't have any effect. What happens if you write a simple Console app that just creates a SmtpClient for that server and attempts to connect? Does that work? You don't have to port your entire program to a Console app, just write a simple Console app to test that MailKit works with your server.

Comment: You are correct: Trying this small console app this is what I get: Error connecting: An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection.

The SSL certificate presented by the server is not trusted by the system for one or more of the following reasons:
1. The server is using a self-signed certificate which cannot be verified.
2. The local system is missing a Root or Intermediate certificate needed to verify the server's certificate.
3. The certificate presented by the server is expired or invalid.

Comment: Okay, that suggests that your SMTP server supports the STARTTLS extension and MailKit is trying to toggle into SSL/TLS mode. To prevent STARTTLS, you can use `Connect ("myhost.com", 25, SecureSocketOptions.None)`.